# Infragistics grid's GET returning empty response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I'm trying to use Infragistics' grid to display a list of items from my Database. I'm using code-first method with Entity Framework in an MVC application with Razor engine. Every thing is working fine in the view except the Infragistics grid.

Here is my home view:

```
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc
@model IEnumerable<BusinessModel.Models.TestPlan>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

@( Html.Infragistics().Grid<BusinessModel.Models.TestPlan>(Model)
.AutoGenerateColumns(true)
.DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("igListTestPlan"))
.DataBind()
.Render())
```

Here is my controller:

```
[GridDataSourceAction]
public ActionResult igListTestPlan()
{
    return View(service.getListTestPlan());
}
```

Using firebug I can clearly see that the request is sent with a status code "200 OK", but the response tab is empty. It also causes an error in the console (in infragistics.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I guess it's because of the empty response.

**What I tried:**

Debugging my controller showed me that `return View(service.getListTestPlan());` doesn't return an empty list: I have 3 valid items in.

I also tried `Html.Infragistics().Grid<BusinessModel.Models.TestPlan>(Model__.ToList())` but nothing changed. Also `Html.Infragistics().Grid(Model)` tells me I've got invalid parameters

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have a pretty good idea why you are getting this, happened to me as well.

The MVC wrappers provide defaults for the way the grid model handles data on the server (serializing the data source to an object with 'Records' of your data and supportive 'Metadata'). However, if you do that yourself since you don't define a key of your own you are stuck with a default key 'Records' that is used to filter the response and since it's not there..well you get 'undefined' data fed to the grid :)

So solutions:

- 1) Wrap your response and define matching key using the "ResponseDataKey" property of the grid. I am suggesting this because as far as I recall it's a good practice to wrap responses in a single object - think there were some security implications.
- 2) If you don't feel like doing this and just want to get it working *now* then set the "ResponseDataKey" to empty string ("" will do) so your response will be properly filtered(or rather not).

On the second part of binding the grid directly to model data in the view - you are correctly getting the error as far as I see. The [DataSource property](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2012.2/CLR4.0?page=Infragistics.Web.Mvc~Infragistics.Web.Mvc.GridModel~DataSource.html) explicitly states the source must implement IQueryable instead of IEnumerable. Slap a .AsQueryable() in there and that should work fine as well.

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: I'll mark this as answer as the second solution worked. Thanks. However, because of the virtual properties from my class, the serializer was not doing his job: I got it to work using a DTO class.

Comment: Serialization is a separate problem sadly as the default .NET ones really only like DTO-s :) And if you are using the MVC grid model to bind to data it will use those.
So far for me JSON.NET has handled most thing very nicely plus it's faster as well and it fits nicely if you are generating the data responses.